# Why isn't my UI update in kotlin jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, parcelable, compose-recomposition

A map comes from another screen and when I make a deletion on that map, the data in the map is deleted, but since there is no UI update, there is no change on the screen, but when I make a change to update the UI, for example, when I go back and come back, then it is deleted, so I realized that this is an indication of this. The element I delete from the list is deleted, but since there is no UI update, I cannot see the change on the UI side. Is there a part I missed? I couldn't find it. Can you please help me? Here is my codes.

**FoodCategoryContent**

this is parcelable data that came from another screen

```
     data class FoodItem(val id: Int?, val name: String?)

     @Parcelize
        data class FoodCategoryContent(
            val selectedFoodList: @RawValue MutableMap<String, MutableSet<FoodItem>> = mutableMapOf()
        ):Parcelable
```

**MY UI:**

```
@Composable
fun FilteredResponseRoute(
    navHostController: NavHostController,
    foodFilterSearchResponse: FoodCategoryContent?,
    viewModel: FilteredResponseViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {

    var doOnce by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
    if (doOnce && foodFilterSearchResponse != null) {
        viewModel.saveTagList(foodFilterSearchResponse.selectedFoodList)
        doOnce = false
    }

    val state by viewModel.state.collectAsState()

    FilteredResponseScreen(
        navHostController,
        state,
        removeTagList = viewModel::removeTagList
    )
}

@Composable
fun FilteredResponseScreen(
    navHostController: NavHostController,
    state: FilteredResponseScreenState,
    removeTagList: (FoodItem, String, Map<String, MutableSet<FoodItem>>) -> Unit
) {

  ... 

  if (state.selectedFilterItems.isNotEmpty()) {
                Row(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .horizontalScroll(rememberScrollState())
                ) {
                    state.selectedFilterItems.forEach { tags ->
                        tags.value.forEach { tag ->
                            FilterCategories(
                                foodItem = tag,
                                key = tags.key,
                                remove = { removedFoodItem, categoryKey ->
                                    removeTagList(
                                        removedFoodItem,
                                        categoryKey,
                                        state.selectedFilterItems
                                    )
                                }
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
     ...
```

**MY VIEWMODEL:**

```
@HiltViewModel
class FilteredResponseViewModel @Inject constructor() : ViewModel() {

    private val _state = MutableStateFlow(FilteredResponseScreenState())
    val state: StateFlow<FilteredResponseScreenState> = _state.asStateFlow()


    fun saveTagList(tagList: Map<String, MutableSet<FoodItem>>) {
        _state.update {
            it.copy(
                selectedFilterItems = tagList
            )
        }
    }

    fun removeTagList(
        removedItem: FoodItem,
        categoryKey: String,
        selectedFilterList: Map<String, MutableSet<FoodItem>>
    ) {

        val categorySet = selectedFilterList[categoryKey]

        if (categorySet != null && categorySet.contains(removedItem)) {
            categorySet.remove(removedItem)

            _state.update { currentState ->
                val updatedFilterList = currentState.selectedFilterItems.toMutableMap()
                updatedFilterList[categoryKey] = categorySet
                currentState.copy(selectedFilterItems = updatedFilterList)
            }
        }
    }
}


data class FilteredResponseScreenState(
    val isLoading: Boolean = false,
    val error: Boolean = false,
    val selectedFilterItems: Map<String, MutableSet<FoodItem>> = mutableMapOf(),
)
```

**SOLVED**

How come I sometimes encounter such problems, but I solved the problem like this

```
   _state.value = state.value.copy(
            tagList = newTagList,
        )
```

Instead of state.update I updated the value like this and it worked